# How to draw images in Latex?

Tags: draw

I'm trying to draw the following picture in LaTeX but I'm having trouble understanding what I should use. I've seen a few examples, but it's hard to adapt them into what I'm looking for.

[image]

If you could help, I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: Dear Helena, i would first decide with which package i will draw, then would search for similar question here on site and then try to accommodate the similarities to my needs ... see http://www.texample.net/. if is there something usable for you

Comment: @KurtK I think OP made it pretty clear he doesn't know where to start. I don't think the _Show us your code_ canned response applies when the asker admits to not even knowing how to approach the problem.

Comment: @jon we aim to please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Here is a simple prototype of what you need. Hopefully, you may apply your desired customizations to it.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  %TikZ central library is called.
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning} % automata and positioning libraries are required to use nodes and coordinates in addition to placement propetries.
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1.0cm,on grid,auto] % Some customizations related to the size and the discatnce between nodes and arrow heads
    \node[state,rectangle, align=center] (q_r) [] {This is a \\ square}; % Here the nodes and coordinates are defined
    \node[coordinate] (q_0) [right=of q_r, xshift=3cm]   {};
    \node[coordinate] (q_1) [left=of q_r, xshift=-3cm, yshift=1mm]   {};
    \node[coordinate] (q_2) [left=of q_r, xshift=-3cm, yshift=-1mm]   {};
    \path[->] % path and draw commands connect the nodes and coordinates to each other.
    (q_r) edge [] node  {This is an arrow} (q_0);   
    \draw[->] ([yshift=-3mm]q_1) -- ([yshift=-2mm]q_r.west) node[midway,swap] {This is an arrow};
    \draw[->] ([yshift=3mm]q_2) -- ([yshift=2mm]q_r.west) node[midway] {This is an arrow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For complicated figures with graphics, I think there is some consensus that `tikz` is the way to go. It is probably worth learning. It is amazing, but can be intimidating for the beginner. For very simple pictures (lines, arrows, text, ovals) the `picture` environment has easy-to-learn tools. The `\put` command together with `\line` and `\vector` commands can recreate your picture.

The basic idea is to `\put` the objects at coordinates relative to the current baseline position. The downside is that small adjustments require recalculating all your coordinates. Lengths and coordinates are in terms of `\unitlength`.

For `\line` and `\vector` commands the format is

```
\line(∆x,∆y){length}
```

The ∆x and ∆y arguments specify the slope (and direction) for lines (and vectors).

Here is the code for an approximation of your picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent I am trying to draw something like this:

\bigskip
\begin{picture}(240,50) % set dimensions of the picture
\put(10,10){\vector(1,0){100}} % lower arrow
\put(30,1){\scriptsize This is an arrow}
\put(10,40){\vector(1,0){100}} % upper arrow
\put(30,44){\scriptsize This is an arrow}
\put(110,0){\line(1,0){120}} % these 4 lines make a rectangle
\put(230,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(110,0){\line(0,1){50}}
\put(110,50){\line(1,0){120}}
\put(230,25){\vector(1,0){100}} % right arrow
\put(250,29){\scriptsize This is an arrow}
\put(142,30){\Large \sffamily This is a}
\put(150,10){\Large \sffamily square}
\end{picture}

\bigskip
\noindent More text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're using commands from the `picture` environment, not from the `graphics` package.

Comment: It doesn't really matter for this simple example, but in general the `xpicture` package has more functionality and fewer arbitrary restrictions than the original `picture` environment. But `picture` has the slight advantage that actually built into the base LaTeX code, so it is available from (and compatible with) every document class in your LaTeX distribution.

Answer (score 8):

A short and simple code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % To compile with pdflatex -shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)%
                                      %  or pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX)
\begin{document}

\psset{arrowinset=0, arrows =->}
\everypsbox{\sffamily \small}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r, colsep=3cm]
\sffamily
\pnode{In} & \psDefBoxNodes{Sq}{\fboxsep=10pt\fbox{\parbox{4cm}{\centering\Large\bfseries This is a \\ square }}} &\pnode{Out}
\ncline[offset=8pt]{In}{Sq:Cl}\naput{This is an arrow}
\ncline[offset=-8pt]{In}{Sq:Cl}\nbput{This is an arrow}
\ncline{Sq:Cr}{Out}\naput{This is an arrow}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

for joy (exploiting answer of [Roboticist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/78499/roboticist) as "your" *mwe*):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}% used tikz libraries

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto,                            % positioning of edges labels
    node distance = 2.5 mm and 40mm, % vertical and horizontal distances between node/coordinates
       box/.style = {rectangle, draw, align=center}% style of node
                        ]
    \node (n1) [box]    {This is\\ a square}; % node with style "box"
    % used coordinates 
    \coordinate[above left=of n1.west]  (in1); 
    \coordinate[below left=of n1.west]  (in2);
    \coordinate[right=of n1.east]       (out);
    arrows
    \draw[-Straight Barb]   % arrows head determined by arrows.meta
        (in1) edge ["This is an arrow"  ] (in1 -| n1.west)
        (in2) edge ["This is an arrow" '] (in2 -| n1.west)% ' means "swap" edge label on another side of adge
        (n1.east) to ["This is an arrow"  ] (out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

code should be self-explanatory ... now i add comments, which describe meaning of using of some code lines. of course, for mastering of `tikz` it is good to read *tikz & pgf manual ...*, at least introduction parts (*1. tutorial*) and then *TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm*.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This could be a job for MetaPost as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib, array}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    input boxes;
    beginfig(1);
        boxit.sqr(btex \begin{tabular}{>{\large\sffamily}c}This is a\\ square\end{tabular}etex);
        drawboxed(sqr);
        z = (3cm, 0);
        drawarrow  sqr.e -- (sqr.e + z);
        label.top (btex This is an arrow etex, sqr.e + .5z);
        pair A[], B[], dir;
        dir = (0, ypart .5[sqr.w, sqr.nw]);
        for i = -1, 1:
            B[i] = sqr.w + i*dir; A[i] = B[i] - z;
            drawarrow A[i] -- B[i];
            label(btex This is an arrow etex, .5[A[i], B[i]]+(0, 2i*labeloffset));
        endfor;
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be typeset with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also draw the picture in Inkscape and export the file as TiKz code using the TiKz Export extension.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I am missing a plain basic tikz solution:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    arrow/.style = {-stealth},
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %square
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,1.5) node[midway,text width=1.4cm,align=center] {This is a \\ square};     
        %arrow
        \draw[arrow] (-4,1) -- (0,1) node [midway,above] {This is an arrow};
        \draw[arrow] (-4,0.5) -- (0,0.5) node [midway,below] {This is an arrow};
        \draw[arrow] (3,0.75) -- (7,0.75) node [midway,above] {This is an arrow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an application with a GUI, ie., Dia. The application can export to LATEX PGF macro's. "Dia is a GTK+ based diagram creation program for GNU/Linux, MacOS X, Unix, and Windows, and is released under the GPL license." (https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia).

You can easily include the diagram as follows in your document, for example:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \vspace{1em}
    \begin{figure}[bth]
        \centering
        \input{this-is-a-square.pgf}
        \caption[This is a square]{This is a square.} 
        \label{fig:thisisasquare}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The pgf file below contains the thisisasquare figure drawn with Dia. Note that the size of the text "This is a square" can be adjusted with the scale property `[framed,scale=0.7,every node/.style={scale=0.8}]`.

```
\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,scale=0.7,every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
\pgftransformxscale{1.000000}
\pgftransformyscale{-1.000000}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (12.400000\du,7.000000\du)--(12.400000\du,12.000000\du)--(25.150000\du,12.000000\du)--(25.150000\du,7.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (12.400000\du,7.000000\du)--(12.400000\du,12.000000\du)--(25.150000\du,12.000000\du)--(25.150000\du,7.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (18.775000\du,9.295000\du){This is a};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (18.775000\du,10.095000\du){square};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.500000\du,8.000000\du)--(12.350000\du,7.950000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.455364\du,11.187328\du)--(12.305364\du,11.137328\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (25.150000\du,9.500000\du)--(32.055364\du,9.437328\du);
}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (6.500000\du,12.700000\du){This is an arrow};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (6.055000\du,7.025000\du){This is an arrow};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (25.855000\du,8.625000\du){This is an arrow};
\end{tikzpicture}
```